# Float sidebar always to the right

Tags: html, css

I just remember me something about float:left; and clear: right; to get the sidebar always to the right. But this is not working for me.

The problem you see on the picture, is that the sidebar is pushed to the bottom of the site by the pagination div.

My markup is:

```
<article></article>
<footer></footer >
<aside class="sidebar"></aside>
```

CSS:

```
aside {
   float:left;
   width: 300px;
   display:inline;
   margin: 0 10px; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the css for `sidebar`

Comment: it does mean the content in article is taking more space than available for side bar to accommodate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the article and footer in a div and add `float:left` to it and then you give the sidebar `float:right` like this:

```
<div class="left">
    <article></article>
    <footer></footer >
</div>

<aside class="sidebar"></aside>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    float:left;
}

.sidebar {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the width percentage to use only float left and clear it in the footer like so:

```css
article {
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: blue;
}
footer {
    clear:both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}

.left{
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<article class="left">ARTICLE</article>
<aside class="sidebar left">ASIDE</aside>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```